# How to add template to TexMaker?

Tags: texmaker, templates

I am new to latex. I downloaded some tutorial to have hand on latex. now what I want to do is to use one of the templates available [here](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/theses) in the texMaker

i downloaded one of the templates but i do not know how to use it in texmaker to produce a pdf containing that template

Comment: Don't. Just don't.

Comment: Download the zip, unpack it and open `main.tex` with texmaker. Nothing more needed. Well, a TeX-distribution is needed and is the most important thing.

Comment: @Johannes_B would u please tell me why? and how to make pdf with a template?

Comment: Why? I have a very very very very strong dislike for templates. They are often buggy and instead of helping the newcommer, it is giving them pain.

Comment: How? Open `main.tex` and hit compile. If no pdf is coming out, the template is bad and you should not use it (make sure to have a working tex-distribution installed).

Comment: @Johannes_B  in the template i downloaded there is nothing called main.tex i have only main.(la)TeX is it the same

Comment: Well, start by telling us which template you want to use.

Comment: @Johannes_B it is here: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

Comment: The main file is called `main.tex`, you editor shows it differently. Extra help that leads to confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb for LaTeX-templates: All templates are packed in a zip file.
The zip file needs to be downloaded<sup>1</sup> and unpacked into a folder of your choice, it contains everything you need.

You should now see a file `main.tex`, which is the important file that you are working on. Rename it to something more unique, for example `elpharoaThesis2016.tex`. Open the file in texmaker and hit compile to test if your installation is ok.

If a pdf called `elpharoaThesis2016.pdf` is created without any error messages, you can go on by editing the meta information and changing the content of the chapters.

Do not change the class file (`MastersDoctoralThesis.cls`).

---

<sup>1</sup> You can use the template directly in Overleaf, an online compiler. No download and no locally installed distribution needed.